# mixin is not a function

Tags: magento2.2, mixins

Hi I have created a mixin but it gives the error "mixin is not a function".

> Vendor/CustomCustomer/view/base/web/customercustom.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'domReady!'
], function ($,_, uiRegistry, Select) {
    'use strict';
    $(function() {
    return function (Select) {
        return Select.extend({
            initialize: function (value) {
                this._super();
                var customerCompany = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_company');
                var defaultCompany = uiRegistry.get('index = extension_attributes.company_attributes.company_id');
                var vessels = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_vessels');
                var customerUsername = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_username');
                var password = uiRegistry.get('index = password');
                var cnfpassword = uiRegistry.get('index = confirm_password');
                if (this.value() != 1) {
                    customerCompany.show();
                    defaultCompany.hide();
                    vessels.show();
                    customerUsername.show();
                    password.show();
                    cnfpassword.show();
                } else {
                    customerCompany.hide();
                    defaultCompany.show();
                    vessels.hide();
                    customerUsername.hide();
                    password.hide();
                    cnfpassword.hide();
                }                
                return this;
            },
            onUpdate: function (value) {
                var customerCompany = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_company');
                var defaultCompany = uiRegistry.get('index = extension_attributes.company_attributes.company_id');
                var vessels = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_vessels');
                var customerUsername = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_username');
                var password = uiRegistry.get('index = password');
                var cnfpassword = uiRegistry.get('index = confirm_password');
                if (value != 1) {
                    customerCompany.show();
                    defaultCompany.hide();
                    customerUsername.show();
                    password.show();
                    cnfpassword.show();
                } else {
                    customerCompany.hide();
                    defaultCompany.show();
                    customerUsername.hide();
                    password.hide();
                    cnfpassword.hide();
                    vessels.hide();
                }

                return this._super();
            },
        });
    }
});
  });
```

> Vendor/CustomCustomer/view/base/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/website': {
                'Vendor_CustomCustomer/customercustom': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to check and change the location of your mixin.
Refer to the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html#location)

Update: Remove single quotes in your mixins declaration:
[reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html#example-1)

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/website': {
                'Vendor_CustomCustomer/customercustom': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response magefms. I have changed the location of my mixin to js/form/element/customercustom. But it is still giving the same error. Please help.

Comment: you mean `web/js/form/element/customercustom` ?

Comment: Yes web/js/form/element/customercustom

Comment: so in your require js it looks like this `'Vendor_CustomCustomer/js/form/element/customercustom': true` ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like this.

Comment: @MeetaliGupta try update in my answer

Comment: magefms, it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having issues with mixin:

- Make sure you're using `define()`, not `require()`. That was the issue for me.
- If you're trying to extend a `$.widget`, **don't include the parent widget as a dependency** inside define(). It's useless and can create silent errors. Declaring `define(['jquery'], ...` should be enough.

Comment: You saved my life